# how to test the TPS in private blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, testing

I have set up a private blockchain and I design a new block structure, I want to test the relationship between TPS and block size, are there already some test tools for this use?

Answer (score 0):

TPS can be calculate as 
gasLimit of block divided gasLimit of transaction divided blocktime.
e.g. If a gasLimit of a block is 4700000,
gasLimit of a transaction is 32000,
blocktime is 10sec
then, (4700000/32000)/10 = 14.68
gasLimit of a block increases dynamically to adjust transaction in a network hence you can achieve 15 to 20 transaction TPS

Comment: Note that all transactions do not require the same amount of gas, depending on what the transaction does.